# Is there any Table Libraries for angular that can refresh cells without rerendering the whole table?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ngx-datatable

In my project I am trying to render a very complex table. Each cells content is given by a cdkPortal. Table also has sorting. Original intention for table is to provide real time data display. So, its data get updated every second. When table's data is changed or sorted whole table gets rerendered. This makes the whole table slow.

Currently I'm using Angular-Material-Table, I've also tried ngx-dataTable. But none of them supports cell level data updation. Does angular has any production level table that support cell level data updation?

Any help is welcomed. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

But, ngx-datatable seems to handle the cell level updation.

How do you update your data ? Did you try to bind your cells to observables ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I update my table by making changes to the input file.
I've never heard of binding cells to observables. Can you please provide me a link on how to do that. In my case cells are populated by portals in angular.